# Unable to load DLL 'git2.dll' The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I'm trying to use [libgit2sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki) in a web-project.  The problem is that libgit2sharp's solution is for VS2010 and I'm using VS2008.  So I had to create a new solution and modify the code not to use default parameters.  That wasn't a problem, except I'm getting the exception listed in the title when I try to use the compiled libgit2sharp DLL.

I've tried linking in the git2.dll, but that hasn't helped.  Copying the git2.dll into the web-project hasn't helped either.

**Edit**: The issue was handled over at the LibGit2Sharp issue tracker: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/39

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I'd say that the `git2.dll` (*compiled version of C [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/) library*) is not in your output directory (`bin\[Release|Debug]`).

As `git2.dll` is not a managed dependency, you cannot reference it from your project.

However, thanks to a prebuild event, you should be able to copy the binary to your output directory.

Another option would be to link to the dll file from within your solution and change its properties to make it 'copied if newer' (see below)

[image]

Should you encounter any problem, please create an issue in the **[bug tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/new)**.

It will be easier to track ;-)

**UPDATE:**

In order for this to run, you have to make sure that after compilation, the file `libgit2.dll` is located in the same directory than the assembly `LibGit2Sharp.dll`. This way, the dynamic loading of the native library by the assembly will work as expected.

The `git2.dll` (*compiled version of C [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/) library*) should be generated **at the top level** of your output directory (`bin\[Release|Debug]`).

More thorough information can be found in the [ticket](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/39)

Comment: Ok, I opened a ticket since that didn't help - I'd already had it linked and copied to all the bin/output folders.

Comment: @Chuck Savage did moving the git2.dll out of the Lib folder, and putting it at the top level of your project, solve your issue?

Comment: @nulltoken: +1 Adding as Link is a nice idea.. Was previously coding the prebuild part..

Comment: @nulltoken: I see we have two binaries one under `amd64` and other under `x86`. My application is a windows 32bit app which runs on both x86 and 64bit(registry: Wow6432Node helps). 
Should I add the `amd64` one also to my project?

Comment: @jacobaloysious: If your app is 32bits only, feel free to only deploy the native 32bit dll. It can either be deployed next to the managed assembly or within a Lib/NativeBinaries/x86 directory structure where it will be loaded from.

Comment: @nulltoken: A 32bit app fails on 64bit OS if I use only 32bit.dll.. I had to add the amd64.dll to make it run..