# Problems loading git2.dll?

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

Im trying to use the libgit2sharp library. My only code is

```
Repository repository = new Repository(@"C:\Path\To\Repo");
```

and when i run it i get an error saying Unable to load DLL 'git2': The specified module could not be found. So, I manually went and grabbed the git2.dll from libgit2sharp and moved it into the directory. When running the same program after that I get another error: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

While researching this I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313203/unable-to-load-dll-git2-dll-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found) and the solution that seemed to work for the poster there didnt work for me. That post was also made a year ago and a supposed fix was made for it, Im using the latest branch of libgit2sharp (ive tried older repositories no change)

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: Target framework is the default, .NET framework 4.0 client

Comment: Also, changing this to 3.5 doesnt change anything

Comment: "Incorrect Format" usually indicates a bitness problem.  Check the "Platform target" setting in the project, and make sure to get the right git library (x86 or amd64) from `libgit2sharp/Lib/NativeBinaries`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended option would be to install the latest **[LibGit2Sharp NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/LibGit2Sharp)** which will take care of installing everything in the correct location.

However, if you prefer to handle this by hand, the GitHub repository includes both `x86` and `amd64` version of the `git2.dll`. Performing a checkout of the `master` or `vNext` branch should retrieve them.

Beware that every version of LibGit2Sharp works against a specific version of the libgit2 binary. Each LibGit2Sharp branch contains a libgit2 submodule which points at the libgit2 commit being wrapped.

[image: submodule]

In order for it to perfectly work, the LibGit2Sharp assembly expects the `git2.dll` binary to be located into a specific tree structure.

```
LibGit2Sharp.dll
|__NativeBinaries
   |__x86
   |  |_git2.dll
   |
   |__amd64
      |_git2.dll
```

Comment: I'm making a VS Extension using a VSIX project. The git2.dll files were getting copied to the bin\Debug|Release directory, but not included in my VSIX package. I ended up having to create the NativeBinaries\amd64 and x86 folder structure in my project, and then link to the git2-3f8d005.dll files as shortcuts. In the shortcut properties I then set the Include In VSIX property to true, and now the assemblies get included in the VSIX with the proper folder structure. It works, but not ideal, cause every time I update the LibGit2Sharp NuGet package I will need to also update the shortcut paths.