# LibGit2Sharp fails to find git2.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I have built a tiny wpf app that manages a website I am working on. The key feature of this app is that it allows me to checkout different branches of a theme repository. This works perfectly in visual studio, but when I publish, install and run the app on my windows 8 machine it comes back with:

```
{"Unable to load DLL 'git2': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}
```

I have searched through the internet and stackoverflow. There are similar questions, such as [Unable to load DLL 'git2.dll' The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313203/unable-to-load-dll-git2-dll-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found) but the answers provided (as well as the answers shown in the github issue described in the answer) bring up another error:

```
Unable to find an entry point git_reference_oid in git2.dll
```

I have tried installing the latest through nuget, including a compiled dll and adding the git2.dll, including the libgit2sharp project in my solution. Once again, it works perfectly when I run it all through visual studio, but fails when I publish, install and run it.

I was unsure what information needed to be included so please feel free to comment and let me know so I can update the question.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computer you're running the installed executable on may lack MSVCR100.DLL or MSVCR110.DLL (depending if git2.dll has been compiled using Visual Studio 2010 or 2012).

A **[fix](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1315)** has been recently merged in libgit2 which removes the need for this dependency.

Indeed, running `dumpbin /IMPORTS git2.dll` against those binaries doesn't show any dependency against MSVCR1x0.dll any longer.

The latest tip of the `vNext` branch of the LibGit2Sharp project embeds those updated git2.dlls. It's recommended to compile the project (using the `build.libgit2sharp.cmd` tool and use this version (manged assembly + native binaries) instead).

Comment: I had tried that earlier, but apparently I didn't put it in the right place. Thank's for the heads up.